# Continuation for a batch file run

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to run bat files in sequence from my code, which I am able to do at the moment with a very simple command:

```
  "start/wait bat_name_1"
```

Unfortunately, at the moment there are some problems and therefore I need to use "wait" in the above command.
Now to run the next bat file, I have to "manually" close the shell or click on any key to execute the next bat file bat_name_1.

I would like to know if there is any way to avoid this manual clicking so that the bat_name_2 should start automatically once the bat_name_1 is finished? Do i need to set any flag or something that indicates that a bat run has finished?

More details:

In my program code (python) I am writing out number of bat files depending on some input "i" where i=1,2,3....

Within the code/interface itself I use shell commands to run them sequentially:

```
    for i .....

     "start/wait bat_name_i"
```

It does work and runs the bat just that it won't start the next bat file till the time I hit a key/ cancel the window. The runs are successful so there is no error. I was looking for a way to avoid the manual work for clicking.

Comment: I have edited my initial question to add more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you wrote

> or click on any key

that sounds like your called batfiles are ending with a `pause` instead of `exit`
So it is not finished, until you press any key (or kill it manually) Therefore your calling batfile waits for the called batfile to finish - as designed.

That means your "error" is in `bat_name_1`

Answer (score 0):

```
"start/wait bat_name_1"
"start/wait bat_name_2"
```

should wait for bat_name_1 to finish before starting bat_name_2

```
"CALL bat_name_1"
"CALL bat_name_2"
```

should do the same

```
"start/wait bat_name_1"
"CALL bat_name_2"
```

likewise.

It's unclear from a single line of code what you are trying to do or why you need to close whichever batch you're closing or even whether the next batch in the sequence is **`the next bat file bat_name_1`**, `bat_1` or `bat_2`

Answer (score 0):

Use `CALL` instead of `START`, unless you really need new windows to be open.

In that case, yes, you will have to flag BAT1 termination to source bat. To do such, you can't use environment, because each window has its own.